# Check between which points a point lies on a spline/bezier curve

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, bezier

Here's what I am trying to solve. I have bezier curves that contain 3 points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) (that are in a 2-dimensional plane). What I am trying to figure out is if a fourth point is clicked by a user on the bezier curves whether the click point lies between points 1 and 2 or if lies between points 2 and 3. The click point is only recorded when the line is directly clicked so it must lie between either points 1 and 2 or points 2 and 3.

The lines are randomly created at compile time and can start and end from any (x, y) position.
[image: example of a curve]

The 3 sets of points that make up the line are the start point, curve point and the end point. These three points are the control points of the line. A line object is then created from the control points. The control points are randomly created during each run of the program, making the spline different every time.

Is there any specific algorithm that should be followed for this problem. I am coding this in javascript but any c++ or java like pseudo code is fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean *quadratic* Bezier curve?

Comment: Are `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)` the control points?  Or arbitrary points known to lie on the curve?

Comment: what do you mean with "between points 1 and 2" and "between points 2 and 3"? If your three points form a genuine curve, then any point inside the triangle {1,2,3} is both between 1 and 2, and between 2 and 3. Can you update your post to explain what you want to achieve more precisely? (ideally, add a picture to show one or more examples of a point configuration and what you want to detect there)

Comment: Your updated post is much clearer, thank you.

Comment: do you need to determine if the user click is even on the curve at all, or is that known?  How is that determined?

Answer (score 3):

Build a LUT (lookup table) for your curve, so that when the user clicks on it, you can resolve the (x,y) coordinate they clicked to the curve's *t* value (or whatever you called your control variable, of course). Rather than evaluating based on (x,y) coordinates, which is virtually impossible, resolve all four coordinates to *t* values, and it becomes really simple:

With (x1,y1) being t=0, (x2,y2) being some t=T and (x3,y3) being t=1, if a user clicks anywhere on the curve, we get a new *t* value. If that value is less than T, the point lies between points 1 and 2, and if it's greater than T, it lies between points 2 and 3.

Build the lookup table should be a one-time operation per curve, run the first time you draw the curve, since that's when you're already mapping *t* values to (x,y) coordinates, so you can build the reverse mapping "for free". If you don't control the draw code, then you'll have to run your own when you create the curve.

That has one problem: the curve you've given here, defined by three on-curve points, is not the usual way to define a Bezier curve. For Bezier curves, the control points define the curve "hull"; for a quadratic curve (with three points), that means points 1 and 3 are on the curve, but point 2 is very much not. To find the true Bezier curve based on these three points (i.e. the curve that goes through those three points) you'd need to run the algorithm that turns three points into a true curve.

(Full code to tell you how to do that is pretty much beyond the scope of this answer, but I explain it in a long article on Bezier curves, culminating in http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#pointcurves for forming true curves based on three points)

Comment: Its not really a bezier curve but more of a spline. All the points are on the curve. I am still confused on how a lookup table would help with this scenario because the points that make up the line will always be different and line would be shaped differently during each run time occurrence.

Comment: you need to give more specific info about the description of the curve. Its defined by control points? How many, etc.

Comment: a LUT always solves your problem, because it's tied to your curve. If you randomly generate the curve, you generate the LUT along with it. If you have a more accurate description of your curve (if a spline, built with what interpolation function(s)?) please update your post and I (and others) can possibly be more specific in my answer.